# Numpy.array(None) returns None but is not None

Tags: python, numpy, nonetype

Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
print np.array(None)
> None
print np.array(None) is None
> False
```

Comment: `print` output is ambiguous. The fact that two things print the same doesn't mean they're the same object, or even that they're equal or that they have the same type. After all, `print 'None'` and `print None` print the same thing, but hopefully you're not surprised that `'None' != None`.

Comment: In addition to all of the other answers, it's worth noting that `np.array(1)` and `np.array(2)` has the same behavior

Answer (score 1):

You have an object that has `None` as the `str()` value, so that's what is printed:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array(None)
array(None, dtype=object)
>>> str(np.array(None))
'None'
```

That's a string value with the letters `N`, `o`, `n` and `e`. That's not the same thing as the `None` singleton object, it just **looks** the same when printed.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have an array object whose string representation is None, and not the `None` object as you suppose:

```
>>> np.array(None)
array(None, dtype=object)
>>> str(_)
'None'
```

Which is why the print statements shows `None`.

However, what you're actually doing is:

```
np.array(None) is None # False
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.array(None)` is not `None`. `print` just prints it as `None`.

```
In [1]: a = np.array(None)

In [2]: a
Out[2]: array(None, dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what it is you're looking to do. What you did is ask if np.array(None) was type None, which it isn't, hence the return of False.